# AJAX print text with style

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using AJAX in order to create chat.

when I reload the replies the texts printed without the css style.

how can I print text with ajax that will include the style?

Thanks

```
$(document).on('submit','#addReply',function(e) {       

    var text = $('#addReply textarea[name=text]').val();
    var chatID =  $("#addReply button").attr("data-ref");
    var lastRefreshReplies = $('#lastRefreshReplies').val();

    var data =  "chatID="+ chatID + "&text=" +text + "&lastRefreshReplies=" +lastRefreshReplies;
    var data = data + "&act=addReply";

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/chatsAjax.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(res){
            if (res != "0")
            {
                $( "#replyRow" ).after(res);

            }

       }
     });

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;   

});
```

chatsAJAX.php file

```
$msgs = add_chat_reply ($_POST, $msgs);
if (empty($msgs['error']))
{
    // print previous reply + the newest reply
    refresh_replies ($_POST['chatID'], $_POST['lastRefreshReplies']);
}
```

FUNC - refresh replies

```
function refresh_replies ($chatID, $lastRefreshReplies)
{

    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM `chats_replies` 
            WHERE (chatID = ".$_POST['chatID'].") AND
                    (createDate > '".$_POST['lastRefreshReplies']."')

    $mainQuery = mysql_query($sql);     
    while($mainIndex = mysql_fetch_array($mainQuery))
    {
        $userName = convert_id_2_value ("users", "name", $mainIndex['userID']);

        $sysName = convert_id_2_value ("users", "name", $mainIndex['system']);  
        $createDate = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($mainIndex['createDate']));

        ?>
        <li class="clear">
            <div class="message-data <?PHP echo $msgAlign?> ">
                <span class="message-data-name  <?PHP echo $msgFloat ?>" ><?PHP echo $userName ?> </span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <span class="message-data-time" ><?PHP echo $createDate ?></span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
            </div>
        </li>           
        <?PHP

    }   
}
```

CSS:

```
.chatReplies .chat-dialog {
  padding: 30px 30px 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
.chatReplies .chat-dialog .message-data {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.chatReplies .chat-dialog .message-data-time {
  color: #a8aab1;
  padding-left: 6px;
}
.chatReplies .chat-dialog .message {
  color: white;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
}
.chatReplies .chat-dialog .message:after {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 7%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-bottom-color: #86BB71;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.chatReplies .chat-dialog .my-message {
  background: #86BB71;
}
.chatReplies .chat-dialog .other-message {
  background: #94C2ED;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Is this really a PHP question or does this happen on client side? What do you mean with "[...] printed without the css style"? That you are missing code highlighting?

Comment: @FabianDamken - I mean that the AJAX print the text that it got from the PHP file, but it doesn't print it with any design/style...

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: If any of the answer have helped you please accept it to point out the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example do it like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/items.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
            $(".result").html(response);
        }
    });
```

But you have to give some more details if it has to be adjusted more to your needs.

In this example your results will be written to the class `result`. You can add css to this class and it will be applied as soon as the ajax data is loaded.

Comment: Show some of your code because I have nothing to refer to right now. When you use the example I show you and you have adde proper css to the class result it should show the style.

Comment: Allright, I think why the style doesn't get added to your data is because you write to the class data while it doesn't exist. Try to add a empty <div class="result"></div> to your html and test it again.

Comment: sure - i added to my first message

Comment: allright, you will have to adjust your css to reach your result class

Comment: adjust? what do you mean? if to call the css file in the ajax page then i tried it and it didn't work...:/

Comment: What I mean is that you, with the ajax I give you, are writing to the element with class result. What you will have to do with your css is adjust it so it fits with the with this element. For example in your html code i don't see a class called .chatRplies. So maybe this should be .result

Answer (score 0):

When you are requesting JSON from your server, it has not format (except for the JSON structure, of course) as JSON is not a human-readable format but nice for computers. To highlight your JSON you must use a JSON beautifier. If you just want to see your JSON pretty right now you can use tools such as [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) that will prettify your JSON.

---

If you want to do it problematically you must search for a "JSON Beautifier" framework (I do not know one right now). Or, if indention is enough, you can use basic JavaScript:

```
JSON.stringify(yourObject, null, '\t')
```

whereas the latter argument is a string of characters that are used for intention.

---

The second argument is a 'replacer' function that may be used to whitelist some properties. Please lookup the documentation of [`JSON.strinigfy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).