# ajax print text without css design

Tags: php, ajax

I have PHP page that print text , with div element , from the DB.
I'm calling to this page with AJAX, but for some reason the text appear on the page without any css design. just the text.

When I check the code with INSPECT ELEMENT (F12) I see the div tags, but no design (no css design).

RES:

```
<li class="clear">
    <div class="message-data align-right ">
        <span class="message-data-name  right" >Roi</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <span class="message-data-time" >26-06-2016 17:52:49</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="message other-message right">
        60          </div>
</li>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('submit','#addReply',function(e) {       

    var text = $('#addReply textarea[name=text]').val();
    var chatID =  $("#addReply button").attr("data-ref");
    var lastRefreshReplies = $('#lastRefreshReplies').val();

    var data =  "chatID="+ chatID + "&text=" +text + "&lastRefreshReplies=" +lastRefreshReplies;
    var data = data + "&act=addReply";

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/chatsAjax.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(res){

            if (res != "0")
            {
                $( "#replyRow" ).after(res);  // <- print text without any design...

            }

       }
     });

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;   

});
```

Comment: You've asked the same question twice before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038826/ajax-print-text-with-style and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039924/respond-from-ajax-without-design

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - can you please give me solution in one of those topics?

Comment: The solutions are there already. They should work. The only problem I have ever encoutered is with background images in Firefox, they might not appear. Asking the browser for a rerender helps. I do that this way: `$("#id_for_div_to_rerender").fadeTo(1500,0.999);` but many other things might invoke a rerender, like: `$("#id_for_div_to_rerender").hide().show(0);` Anyway, I don't think this is your problem.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - I tried it with IE, there also i got no design...

Comment: The best thing you can do, if you cannot solve this problem yourself, is to either give us a complete example, or a link to a working page (although they don't appear to like the latter option here on Stack Overflow). We simply cannot tell what's going wrong from the bits of code you provide.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, ok, can you please take a look here in my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038826/ajax-print-text-with-style

Comment: That question is missing the main HTML page. I cannot turn it into a working example that does the same as you have. First simplify, and if the problem persist, the code will be so short you can easily share all of it.

Answer (score 0):

Add your css files in chatsAjax.php,so that it will render the div
your response should be like this

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path to your css">
 <li class="clear">
   <div class="message-data align-right ">
    <span class="message-data-name  right" >Roi</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <span class="message-data-time" >26-06-2016 17:52:49</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
</div>
<div class="message other-message right">
    60          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you load content via Ajax somewhere in an HTML document, that content will be "raw" with no styles.

Add (link) the styles **to the container html page** where the stuff is gonna be loaded, and be sure that the loaded HTML content is "correct", no typos, no wrong code. This should be enough.

Comment: I tried to call CSS file from everywhere and still nothing:
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/chats.css">'; or echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/chats.css">';

Comment: Could you please paste your code? Ajax call, html files, etc. Use this if necessary: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: here i post all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038826/ajax-print-text-with-style

Comment: Fine, but where's the html where you're inserting the results of the ajax call? o_O

Comment: this HTML is also built with AJAX...with another query. can it be the reason why the css isn't show?

Comment: ah! then, maybe this will help you: Load CSS with AJAX: http://deano.me/2012/09/jquery-load-css-with-ajax-all-browsers/